# Matplotlib pyinstaller error failed to execute

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pysimplegui

My .exe generated is failed to execute with a matplotlib program.

> > 54 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.0 54 INFO: Python: 3.7.8rc1 57 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0 58 INFO: wrote
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\Chart.spec
> > 59 INFO: UPX is not available. 61 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with
> > paths ['c:\Users\vnareshk\Desktop\UPH\pythonProject',
> > 'C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts']
> > 69 INFO: checking Analysis 69 INFO: Building Analysis because
> > Analysis-00.toc is non existent 70 INFO: Initializing module
> > dependency graph... 73 INFO: Caching module graph hooks... 86 INFO:
> > Analyzing base_library.zip ... 1622 INFO: Processing pre-find module
> > path hook distutils from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-distutils.py'.
> > 1624 INFO: distutils: retargeting to non-venv dir
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib'
> > 2624 INFO: Caching module dependency graph... 2711 INFO: running
> > Analysis Analysis-00.toc 2726 INFO: Adding
> > Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final
> > executable   required by
> > c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe
> > 2785 INFO: Analyzing
> > c:\Users\vnareshk\Desktop\UPH\pythonProject\Chart. 3339 INFO:
> > Processing pre-find module path hook site from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_find_module_path\hook-site.py'.
> > 3340 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\fake-modules'
> > 6847 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook
> > setuptools.extern.six.moves from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-setuptools.extern.six.moves.py'.
> > 10194 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook six.moves from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-six.moves.py'.
> > 12483 INFO: Processing module hooks... 12483 INFO: Loading module hook
> > 'hook-certifi.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...
> > 12491 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pycparser.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...
> > 12492 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-distutils.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 12493 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 12583 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-lib2to3.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 12630 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-matplotlib.backends.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 13120 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
> > backend Gtk3Agg requires cairo 13381 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
> > cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed 13629 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
> > cannot import name '*macosx' from 'matplotlib.backends' (c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends_*init**.py)
> > 13873 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
> > No module named 'IPython' 14206 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": ignored
> > Failed to import any qt binding 14456 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Cairo": ignored
> > cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed 14776 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": ignored
> > Failed to import any qt binding 15020 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Cairo": ignored
> > cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed 15467 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added 15902 INFO:
> > Matplotlib backend "TkCairo": ignored
> > cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed 16314 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added 16733 INFO:
> > Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
> > No module named 'wx' 16975 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
> > No module named 'wx' 17218 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXCairo": ignored
> > No module named 'wx' 17529 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added 17772 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
> > cairo backend requires that pycairo>=1.11.0 or cairocffiis installed 18185 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added 18604 INFO:
> > Matplotlib backend "pgf": added 18911 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps":
> > added 19226 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added 19649 INFO:
> > Matplotlib backend "template": added 19858 INFO: Loading module hook
> > 'hook-matplotlib.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20112 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.core.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20180 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-numpy.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20181 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.Image.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20480 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-PIL.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20482 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'PyQt4' 20482 INFO:
> > Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk' 20483 INFO: Excluding import
> > 'PyQt5' 20484 INFO:   Removing import of PyQt5 from module PIL.ImageQt
> > 20485 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter' 20487 INFO:   Removing import
> > of tkinter from module PIL.ImageTk 20487 INFO: Import to be excluded
> > not found: 'PySide' 20487 INFO: Loading module hook
> > 'hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20489 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter' 20490 INFO: Import to be
> > excluded not found: 'FixTk' 20490 INFO: Loading module hook
> > 'hook-pkg_resources.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 20911 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook win32com from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\pre_safe_import_module\hook-win32com.py'.
> > 20980 WARNING: Hidden import "pkg_resources.markers" not found! 20981
> > INFO: Excluding import '**main**' 20983 INFO:   Removing import of
> > **main** from module pkg_resources 20984 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-setuptools.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21497 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-sysconfig.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21498 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.dom.domreg.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21499 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21500 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-xml.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21500 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-_tkinter.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks'...
> > 21674 INFO: checking Tree 21674 INFO: Building Tree because
> > Tree-00.toc is non existent 21676 INFO: Building Tree Tree-00.toc
> > 21734 INFO: checking Tree 21734 INFO: Building Tree because
> > Tree-01.toc is non existent 21736 INFO: Building Tree Tree-01.toc
> > 21746 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pythoncom.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...
> > 22055 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pywintypes.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...
> > 22359 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-win32com.py' from
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\stdhooks'...
> > 22704 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs 22758 INFO: Analyzing run-time
> > hooks ... 22764 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
> > 22767 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
> > 22768 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
> > 22770 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
> > 22772 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
> > 22772 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
> > 22773 INFO: Including run-time hook
> > 'c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_certifi.py'
> > 22786 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries 23468 INFO: Looking for eggs
> > 23469 INFO: Using Python library
> > c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
> > 23471 INFO: Found binding redirects: [] 23480 INFO: Warnings written
> > to
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\build\Chart\warn-Chart.txt
> > 23603 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\build\Chart\xref-Chart.html
> > 23664 INFO: checking PYZ 23665 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc
> > is non existent 23667 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive)
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\build\Chart\PYZ-00.pyz
> > 25350 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive)
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\build\Chart\PYZ-00.pyz
> > completed successfully. 25386 INFO: checking PKG 25386 INFO: Building
> > PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent 25388 INFO: Building PKG
> > (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg 33608 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
> > completed successfully. 33643 INFO: Bootloader
> > c:\users\vnareshk\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
> > 33643 INFO: checking EXE 33647 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc
> > is non existent 33648 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc 33648 INFO:
> > Appending archive to EXE
> > C:\Users\vnareshk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\dist\Chart.exe
> > 33674 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

Here is my code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def draw_plot():
    plt.plot([0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 0.7,0.2])
    plt.show(block=False)
layout = [[sg.Button('Plot'), sg.Cancel(), sg.Button('Popup')]]
window = sg.Window('Have some Matplotlib....', layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Cancel'):
        break
    elif event == 'Plot':
        draw_plot()
    elif event == 'Popup':
        sg.popup('Yes, your application is still running')
window.close()
```

Comment: Put `console = True` in your myspec file, then execute your .exe and check what is the error in the console.

Comment: _"Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully."_ This is what the code says, what error did you experience, did you try running the file in the `dist` folder? Include the error codes too

Comment: When I run the exe file, I get "Fatal error, failed to execute the script chart".

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered problems like this. Here's what I suggest:

First, compile your code like this

```
pyinstaller -F your_script.py
```

This will compile into an .exe and leave a debug window open in the background that will display necessary information for next steps.

Next, locate and run your .exe. Before the script fails you will see on the debug window the error that's causing the crash. The biggest culprit I've seen lately is the
`pkg_resources.py2_warn` import error.

Last, add an import statement at the top of your code that forces the import of whatever is causing pyinstaller to build a bad .exe. For instance, with the pkg_resources error I was having I ended up adding:

```
import pkg_resources.py2_warn
```

And now it compiles properly and the executable works.